# Is being able to execute a GSGL (OpenGL Shader File) remote code execution?

Tags: security

I'm wondering if executing a user/attacker-provided GSGL file is a security vulnerability. I am wondering what, security wise, you could do with executing one in OpenGL on an iOS device. I do not know how GSGL could be used by an attacker, so a demonstration on how would also be nice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a friend who has answered this for me: *no*, it is not considered RCE because it only affects the graphics card and not the memory.